# Scala macro expand to compiler option

Tags: scala, macros

My original task is to have some object containing a distribution version of my application currently installed. This is necessary to be able to request the currently running version via http-endpoint (different clients run different versions).

So I thought that was a perfect task for macro. The problem is my build system is maven and I thought of passing the version number (available in maven properties in `pom.xml` as a compile option to retrieve it later from macro).

```
object ProjectVersion {
   def applicationVersion(): String = macro getVersion
   def getVersion(c: Context)(): c.Expr[Unit] = {
      //?
   }
}
```

Googling the problem did not give any sensible result. Can someone please give an advice if it is even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be very simple. There is a specific [compiler option](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html)

> `-Xmacro-settings OPTION1,OPTION2`
>     Custom settings for macros.

So providing that the only macro setting passed is the version number we can add the following macro implementation:

```
object Version {
  def versionNumber(): String = macro debug_impl

  def versionNumber_impl(c: whitebox.Context)(): c.Expr[String] = {
    import c.universe._
    val paramRepTree = c.Expr[String](Literal(Constant(c.settings.head)))
    reify { paramRepTree.splice }
  }
}
```

Using it is also simple

```
object TestMacro extends App{
  import Version._
  println(versionNumber()) // prints 0.1-SNAPSHOT for my pom.xml
}
```